# Can you tell me which two fonts are used in this image?

Tags: font-identification

Can you tell me which two fonts are used in this image?

[image]

Comment: I know the hand written font is called Sue Ellen.  I found that one.  But still looking for the title font - jennifer

Answer (score 1):

At first glance it looks like Futura but that's not quite right, the terminals of the `S` and `C` are less curved. After some digging around I found Twentieth Century which was created as a competitor to Futura. I think it's a match, see Twentieth Century in [Medium](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/twentieth-century-mt/pro-medium/glyphs.html) and [Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/twentieth-century-mt/pro-bold/).

Comment: I feel that there is a huge need to identify fonts and some computer scientist should develop a machine learning algorithm for it.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/  gives results based on image of font you upload

[image]

[image]

.
You can also use search term is **identify fonts online** if you prefer a different site

[image]